# WooCommerce OnClick Add to Cart Not Firing?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I'm trying to get my Facebook Conversion Tracking code to fire when someone clicks the Add to Cart button. I've made the following changes, although Facebook is still show the pixel as unverified.

I'm not sure if the ajax add to cart is interfering with the onclick event.

This is my add to cart button:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" onclick="facebookConversionPixel(%s);" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_price() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

This is the part of my loop-start.php file:

```
<script> 
function facebookConversionPixel(fb_value){   
    var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '6018460172323', {'value':+ fb_value,'currency':'USD'}]);
}
</script>
<ul class="products clearfix products-<?php echo $woocommerce_loop['columns']; ?>">
```

I just added the fb_value, I'm not sure if I added it correctly. I did try it without and still not showing verified on Facebook's end.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following script the info is loaded on the page and waits for the add to cart button to fire the tracking code and dollar amount.

```
<script>
(function () {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
function facebookConversionPixel(fb_value) {
  window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
  window._fbq.push(['track', '6018460172323', {'value':fb_value,'currency':'USD'}]);
}
</script>
```